# Access 2003 - count unique values

Tags: sql, ms-access

How to count unique values in Access 2003? 
When i write sth like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer FROM CustomersTable;
```

I've got as result unique customers, but how count them if this code doesn't work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
```

`FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Customer FROM CustomersTable )`

(it causes error: "The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query 'SELECT DISTINCT Customer FROM CustomersTable'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly")

*Example of database*

```
--Customer -- Address -- 
X               NY 
X               OR 
Y               AR 
Z               WA
```

And I'd like to have as result 3 (three unique Customers.)

Comment: The syntax is valid and counts the number of distinct `Customer` values. Does it work for you?

Comment: I've got error: 
The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query 'SELECT DISTINCT Customer FROM CustomersTable'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.

Comment: did you tried this:

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Customer) FROM CustomersTable;

Comment: Jet/ACE SQL does not support COUNT(DISTINCT).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select 
    Customer, 
    count(Customer) as count
from
    CustomersTable
group by
    Customer
```

Alright, You should try this now:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Customer) FROM CustomersTable;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: please edit it in your question. create a table like structure to show it more clearly. I didn't get a thing which you mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Won't that output a list `(X, 2) (Y, 1) (Z, 1)`? If I understood the OP correctly, he just wants an output of `3`.

Comment: But 
`SELECT COUNT(Customer)
FROM [SELECT Customer, count(Customer) AS [count]
FROM Main
GROUP BY Customer];`
works fine... I have no idea why it can't be written easier...

Comment: @Amber: `Main`? I thought your table was called `CustomersTable`? Yes, the double count is surely unnecessary.

Comment: Alright, You should try this:

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Customer) FROM CustomersTable;

Comment: @AlphaMale: Raj already tried this as an answer, see his answer.

Comment: No Henzi, my mistake in writting - it's still called CustomerTable

Comment: @Amber: CustomerTable or Customer*s*Table? These differences are very important...

Comment: I believe Heinzi answer to be correct and this to be incorrect.

Comment: Names are correct. As I wrote earlier `SELECT DISTINCT Customer FROM CustomersTable; ` work. and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Customer FROM CustomersTable ) as T` doesn't work . Name of table was the first thing which I suspected to be wrong, but after it wasn't this i wrote here.

Comment: @Amber If you use the same idea on a table in a different database, do you have the same problems?

Comment: Access/Jet/ACE SQL does not support COUNT(DISTINCT).

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your subquery a name:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Customer FROM CustomersTable) AS T
```

Comment: It doesn't work too. 
"The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query 'SELECT DISTINCT Customer FROM CustomersTable'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly."

Comment: @Amber: Are you sure that you are using round parenthesis `(SELECT ...) AS T` and not square ones `[SELECT ...]`? As far as I remember, the Access Query Designer has a tendency of converting the former into the latter...

Comment: @Amber: And CustomersTable is a regular table in the same DB? (Sorry for the stupid question, but it really should work...)

Comment: I know, because I used subquery like this at home in a different database and it works, and now in my office it doesn't, so I'm suprised too.

Comment: @Amber: Maybe you have a different Access version at the office? Subqueries in the FROM clause were not supported in old versions of Access...

Comment: in 2003 they're not supported? I think they should be. Especially, that sth like this `SELECT COUNT(Customer) FROM [SELECT Customer, count(Customer) AS [count] FROM CustomersTable GROUP BY Customer]; ` works fine.

Comment: @Amber: They should be supported in 2003; I don't remember the exact version when they were introduced.

Comment: Standard SQL requires you to give the derived table a name but it works for me in Access (ACE, Jet, whatever) without the name.

Comment: I've never quite figured out when Access is happy with round brackets and when it requires the old-style square brackets (with trailing period).

Answer (score 0):

Edit (Query Corrected)

This worked for me in Access 2007

```
SELECT Count(*) AS NumCustomers
FROM 
(
    SELECT Distinct CustomerAddress.Customer
    FROM CustomerAddress
)  AS DistinctCustomers;
```

Comment: AFAIK, this syntax is not supported by Access.

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'COUNT (DISTINCT Customer)'

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was probably abandoned a long time ago but just for anyone who is having this issue, as I was having errors using a C# application to do a similar task and found refuge here:
http://www.geeksengine.com/article/access-distinct-count.html

This helped me a lot and if broken, gave the following query structure

```
    SELECT COUNT(columnName) as num_ofColumnNameEntries
    from
       (
        SELECT DISTINCT columnName FROM TableName
       )
```